# xml from xib - field name nil with key

Tags: xml, xcode, xib

I'm looking into the xml side of a xib file to understand the way it works. surprisingly, there is quite no documentation about it.

here is my problem

```
<view contentMode="scaleToFill" id="iN0-l3-epB">
        <rect key="frame" x="0.0" y="0.0" width="375" height="667"/>
        <autoresizingMask key="autoresizingMask" widthSizable="YES" heightSizable="YES"/>
        <subviews>
            <label opaque="NO" userInteractionEnabled="NO" contentMode="scaleToFill" horizontalHuggingPriority="251" verticalHuggingPriority="251" fixedFrame="YES" text="Label" textAlignment="center" lineBreakMode="tailTruncation" baselineAdjustment="alignBaselines" adjustsFontForContentSizeCategory="YES" adjustsFontSizeToFit="NO" translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints="NO" id="wwI-XT-LR8">
                <rect key="frame" x="116" y="31" width="92" height="90"/>
                <autoresizingMask key="autoresizingMask" flexibleMaxX="YES" flexibleMaxY="YES"/>
                <fontDescription key="fontDescription" type="system" pointSize="17"/>
                <nil key="textColor"/>
                <nil key="highlightedColor"/>
            </label>
        </subviews>
        <color key="backgroundColor" red="1" green="1" blue="1" alpha="1" colorSpace="custom" customColorSpace="sRGB"/>
        <viewLayoutGuide key="safeArea" id="vUN-kp-3ea"/>
        <point key="canvasLocation" x="-52.5" y="-93.5"/>
    </view>
```

all the information present in the xml can be found as settable options on xcode interface. but,

```
 <nil key="textColor"/>
   <nil key="highlightedColor"/>
```

I just dont understand those two. ok they are options, settable on xcode interface etc, but checking or unchecking `highlightedColor` on xcode does not affect the value on the xml side of the file.

Is any of you could explain me why those fields are named `nil` and knows how to set those value from xml side ?

Comment: Have you found an answer to this?

Answer (score 5):

I stumbled upon this thinking it was a malformed XIB file. But in fact this nil key represents the *Default* text color and highlighted color for UILabels. When there is any value in them, they are represented such as `<color key="highlightedColor" red="1" green="1" blue="0.50859917529999998" alpha="1" colorSpace="calibratedRGB"/>`, else they are `<nil key="highlightedColor"/>` etc.